# importing .py files indefinitely

Tags: python

i'm a newcomer to python, and i would like to try moving from one file to another, like looping through fileA then fileB indefinitely. However, when i tried to use the import function, the files only import each other once, then stop. is there a way to import the whole file multiple times?

FileA:

```
story1 = "You see a statue of a metal man peeking out of a building. A park is just across the street.\n\nPossible exits: north."
map_legend = "\nMap Legend:\nG   you\n.   clear path\n-|  wall\n+   door\n"
map1 = "-.\n |G\n-//\n|.|\n---"

while True:
    print(story1)
    action = input(str())
    while action != 'north':
            print ('there is nothing there.')
            action = input(str())
    ***import story2***
    continue
```

FileB:

```
story2 = "You see a map on the bench. Type 'grab' to pick it up.\n\nPossible exits: north and south."
map_legend = "\nMap Legend:\nG   you\n.   clear path\n-|  wall\n+   door\n"
map1 = "-.\n |G\n-//\n|.|\n---"
inventory=list()
action = 'north'

while True:
    print(map_legend,"\n",map1,"\n")
    direction = f"you moved {action}."
    print(direction)
    print(story2)
    action = input(str())
    while action != 'north' and action != 'south' and action != 'grab':
        print ('there is nothing there.')
        action = input(str())
    if action == 'grab':
        inventory.append('1 map')
        print ("Inventory:\n1 map")
        action = input(str())
    while action != 'north' and action != 'south':
        print ('there is nothing there.')
        action = input(str())
    if action == 'south':
        direction = f"you moved {action}."
        print(direction)
        ***import story1***
        continue
```

So, there was no problem moving from fileA to fileB, but after moving from fileB to fileA, i couldn't "import" fileB anymore. Is the "import" function being used wrongly here?

Thanks.

Comment: Despite it's not an answer to your question - i strongly believe that constant loop of importing two files is not the best logic to make an app. If you want to use code from another file - it's better to make some functions in this files and use them when you need.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to put the code that you want to re-use in [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), then you can call the functions repeatedly do do what you want.

For example:

A.py

```
def do_thing():
    # some code

def do_other_thing():
    # more code
```

B.py

```
import A

while True:
    A.do_thing()
    A.do_other_thing()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your code directly in the `.py` file, each file should define a *function* (using the `def` keyword). Then you can `import` the functions from those files and call them one after another, in a loop.

That said, if you *really* want to re-import the module (instead of just reusing the existing module object, which the `import` statement does), you can use [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

Answer (score 0):

Define a function in fileA and fileB. Use these files with their function to import in your module and create a loop which calls each other. But, this is not a good way to go for.